# MBTA Google Places API

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

Maybe this is the wrong place for this, but I can't seem to find anywhere else to find out. Does anyone know if it is possible to access the MBTA (subway, the T, whatever you call it - the non-bus/commuter-rail part) stations in the google places API?  I keep trying to do transit_station or subway_station but for some reason it always returns with no results. However, when I look up transportation in Boston on Google Maps, it gives me the subway lines as an option. Any idea why this is the case?

Comment: I'm not sure if you can do that either. Did you try messing with the MBTA API?
http://www.mbta.com/rider_tools/developers/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both transit_station and subway_station look like they work.  Doesn't look like all of them are available in the Places API though:

http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_place-search_MBTA.html

A [FusionTables based MBTA map](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_FusionTables_MBTA.html) (not what you were looking for, but...)

Comment: What you sent is missing entire train lines though, weirdly enough.